# Android jetpack compose navigation between screens error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I got the following error when I try to navigate between screens in jetpack compose,
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.notification, PID: 9386
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY`

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihlBr.png)

My NAVGRAPH

```
@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screens.MainScreen.route) {
        composable(
            route = Screens.MainScreen.route
        ) {
            MainScreen(navController)
        }

        composable(
            route = Screens.DetailScreen.route,
        ) {
            DetailsScreen(navController)
        }
    }
}
```

My screens sealed class

```
sealed class Screens(val route: String) {
    object MainScreen : Screens(route = "main")
    object DetailScreen : Screens(route = "detail")
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val notificationManager: NotificationManagerCompat,
    private val notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder
) : ViewModel() {
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun showSimpleNotification() {
        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun updateNotification() {
        notificationBuilder.setContentText("Updated Content")
        notificationManager.notify(
            1,
            notificationBuilder.setContentText("this is the message from the update").build()
        )

    }

    fun cancelNotification() {
        notificationManager.cancel(1)
    }
}
```

I try to navigate between tow screens in jetpack compose, i did this many times before but now i got this problem.

Comment: seems like a problem with your viewmodel, can you provide more info about that?

Comment: I've idded my ViewModel

Comment: What class does your activity extend (e.g., `ComponentActivity`, `FragmentActivity`, or `AppCompatActivity`)? What are your `dependencies` in your `build.gradle` file? The `CreationExtras` APIs require a minimum version of Activity / Fragment as per [the Lifecycle release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.5.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar problem before. In my case, just in case, I went into the appdan build.gradle and checked the defundancy, and only `androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose` was connected. That's right. I only connected the Hilt navigation system, but I didn't connect the Compose navigation defense.

Just add a compost navigation system and we'll be able to solve the problem.

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3"
```

My app only consists of pure Jetpack Compose, so this is the only way to solve the problem, but if you're using Fragment together and you're experiencing problems even if you add the defendancy above, try adding the defendancy below.

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.4"
```